# Order topology on a poset

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

How does the open rays on a partially ordered set $X$ forms a subbasis for a topology on $X$ (which is called order topology) ? I was considering the case $X$ has only one element.

Moreover, I know if the order is linear, then the order topology is Hausdorff. But now the question is: Does there exists another condition on the ordering such that the topology is Hausdorff?

Comment: I guess an "open ray" is a set of the form $(a,\to) = \{x \in X : x>a\}$ or dually?  What conditions do you need to check to see whether a collection of sets is a subbase for a topology?

Comment: @GEdgar Sir, for a subbase, the union of the elements of the subbasis should cover whole of X.